# Caching SOQL Query Results - with a List of Id's in the condition

Tags: apex, soql

How do I write a utility method to cache the SOQL results with a List of Id's in the where clause as below:

```
List<Id> accOwnerIds = new List<Id>();
Map<Id, User> mapUser= [select id, name, profile.name from user where id in :accOwnerIds];
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to save the results to `mapUser` so that the SOQL query is only done once no matter how many times `mapUser` is used?

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to save the results of mapUser for reusability. I would like to write a utility method which would take the parameter of a list of accOwnerIds and return a map.

Answer (score 0):

You can make utility function like this:

```
private static Map<Id, User> getUsers(List<Id> accOwnerIds)
{
   return [select id, name, profile.name from user where id in :accOwnerIds];
}
```

Use this function anywhere in class by class name. If there is a need of similar type of structure in more than one classes then you can create a utility class and place this method there, but make sure its accessibility modifier should be public.

Comment: Isn't this method hitting the database every time? If it were a single parameter, i would have cached the result object in a map against that parameter. The question here is around the parameter being a list instead of a single value, which is making it difficult to store it against the result.